# Why are some Javascript functions put inside $()?

Tags: javascript

I've noticed some functions in Javascript are contained within **$()**.  For example:

```
$(function() {
     //do something here
});
```

As opposed to simply:

```
function() {
     //do something here
};
```

I know this notation isn't needed for a Javascript function to work, so what does the $() actually do?

Comment: This is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) lingo.

Comment: Ah I see!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Jquery's short hand for `$(document).ready(function(){});`

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

By the way, your second function will never be executed. You need to add `()` if you want it to be executed.

```
function() {
     //do something here
}();
```